# Using JSON requests in Google App Engine (Go programming language)

Tags: json, google-app-engine, go

I am trying to send requests in JSON format from the Javascript front-end of my application to  App Engine using Go. How do I parse the request to a struct in the handler?

Say for example my request is a POST with the request payload

```
{'Param1':'Value1'}
```

and my struct is

```
type Message struct {
    Param1 string
  }
```

and the variable

```
var m Message
```

The examples in the app engine documentation use the FormValue function for getting standard request values, and this doesn't seem to work when you use json.

A simple example would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send the data in a form field, but typically you'll just read it from the `response.Body`. Here's a minimal jQuery & App Engine example:

```
package app

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

func init () {
    http.HandleFunc("/", home)
    http.HandleFunc("/target", target)
}

const homePage =
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/target" id="postToGoHandler">
    <input type="submit" value="Post" />
    </form>
    <div id="result"></div>
<script>
$("#postToGoHandler").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post("/target", JSON.stringify({"Param1": "Value1"}),
        function(data) {
            $("#result").empty().append(data);
        }
    );
});
</script>
</body>
</html>`

func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, homePage)
}

type Message struct {
    Param1 string
}

func target(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    defer r.Body.Close()
    if body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Couldn't read request body: %s", err)
    } else {
        dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(string(body)))
        var m Message
        if err := dec.Decode(&m); err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "Couldn't decode JSON: %s", err)
        } else {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "Value of Param1 is: %s", m.Param1)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The official documentation is pretty good, see:

http://golang.org/doc/articles/json_and_go.html

It has examples both for encoding/decoding to a known structure (your example), but also shows how to do it using reflection, similar to how you would typically do it in more scripty languages.

Comment: The problem I have is that I do not know which part of the request (type *http.Request) to pass to the Decode function (which requires an io.Reader as input).

Comment: For a POST request, use the response body. That should contain the "raw" JSON data (simply a JSON encoded data structure, which is a simple string).

Comment: It actually depends on the server, how it sends back the JSON data. It's typically done using the response body.

Comment: If you need to send JSON (which you are probably trying to, based on me rereading your question), you need to encode it to a string, and send it as a POST (named) field. But it needs to be the in the same named field as where the server expects to find it.